# Rounding to a power of 10

Tags: matlab, rounding, logging, exponent

I have a variable, `tauMax`, that I want to round *up* to the nearest power of ten(1, 10, 100, 1000...). I am using the below expression to find the closest integer to the max value in the tau array. I am finding the max value because I am trying to calculate the power of ten that should be the x axis cutoff. In this cause, tauMax is equal to 756, so I want to have an expression that outputs either 1000, or 3(for 10^3).

```
tauMax = round(max(tau));
```

I'd really appreciate any help!

Comment: You could also do this I believe based off of the number of digits.

Comment: That's a great idea. Do you know what command i would use to find the number of digits in a given number?

Comment: @Alex Nichols - Since you're talking base 10 just use `log10` (see my answer below).

Comment: Seems to be some different ways to do that: http://www.mathworks.co.jp/matlabcentral/answers/10795-counting-the-number-of-digits, but the other method may be easier.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since you're talking base 10, you could just use `log10` to get the number of digits.

How about:

```
>> ceil(log10(756))

ans =

     3
```

Comment: Very nice, and works just the same using python `math` as @steveha answers also

Answer (score 7):

I don't really do Matlab, but the usual way to do this in any language I do know is: take the logarithm base 10, then round up that number to the nearest integer, then compute 10 to the power of that number.  In Python:

```
from math import ceil, log

def ceil_power_of_10(n):
    exp = log(n, 10)
    exp = ceil(exp)
    return 10**exp

>>> print(ceil_power_of_10(1024))  # prints 10000
```

Comment: Doesn't it print 10000?

Comment: @Nils_M Yes, it prints 10000.  Thanks for the correction!  I'll edit the answer and correct the comment.