# How to force numbers into [1,10) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have some numbers, for example:

`1.1, 10, 2.2*1.0e+45, 2.2*1.0e-44`

I do not know exact what is the next number will be but I want to remove the scientific part of the number, i.e. reduce each number in magnitude to the half-open interval [1,10).The output values have to be like:

`1.1, 1, 2.2, 2.2`

How to achieve this in MATLAB?

Comment: You example is unclear. Are those numbers written in a string? If they are just numbers on MATLAB they do not have scientific notation, they are just shown like that to you (and you can change it with e.g. `format long g`). If you just want to remove all and just get the number, why is 10 not 1.0?

Comment: @AnderBiguri thx, I made a mistake, yes, it should be 1.0.

Comment: And ho wmany floating point digits do you want? would 123456789 be 1.23456789 or 1.2?

Comment: How would you do this mathematically?

Comment: @Fly_back by the way, the numbers you are looking for are often called the [significand or the mantissa](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Significand).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its as easy as finding the previous power of ten and divide by that.

```
num=123456789;

num/10^floor(log10(num));

ans=
>>1.23456789
```

Reference: [Rounding to a power of 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769406/rounding-to-a-power-of-10)